# A counterexample for weak convergence

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Find two sequence of probability measures $\{\mu_n\}$ and $\{\nu_n\}$ such that
$$\forall f\in C_K:\int f\mathrm{d}\mu_n-\int f\mathrm{d}\nu_n\rightarrow 0.$$
but for no finite $(a,b)$ is it true that
$$\mu_n(a,b)-\nu_n(a,b)\rightarrow0.$$

It is an exercise in Kai Lai Chung's book, here is a hint: let $\mu_n=\delta_{r_n}$ and $\nu_n=\delta_{s_n}$  and choose $\{r_n\}$ and $\{s_n\}$ suitable.

Comment: This is an interesting exercise. I guess that $C_K$ denotes the set of continuous functions with compact support defined on the real line. did you try to follow the hint?

Comment: Yes, $C_K$ denotes the set of continuous functions with compact support. I try to follow the hint, but I can not find the suitable $r_n$ and $s_n$.

Comment: What happens with these integrals if the sequences are increasing and unbounded?

Comment: Then $ \mu_n(a,b)-\nu_n(a,b)\rightarrow0$ for all $(a,b)$.

Comment: What's the example for finite intervals with rational end points?

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my construction.

Comment: There was an error in my construction as well. Thanks to @geetha290krm for pointing that. The sequences $r_n$ and $s_n$ have to be dense in $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_N=\sum_{\ell=1}^{N-1}2\ell^2$. For $A_N\leqslant n\leqslant A_{N+1}-1$, let
$r_n:=-N+(n-A_N)/N$ (in other words, we start at $-N$ and go to $N$ by steps of length $1/N$). If $A_N\leqslant n\leqslant A_{N+1}-1$, let $s_n=r_n+1/N$.
In this way, $\lvert r_n-s_n\rvert\to0$ and the requirement
$$
\forall f\in C_K:\int f\mathrm{d}\mu_n-\int f\mathrm{d}\nu_n\rightarrow 0
$$
holds by uniform continuity of each $f\in C_K$.

For the second one, note that for $N\geqslant b$ and such that $1/N<b-a$, there is $n$ such that $r_n\in (a,b)$ but $s_n\notin (a,b)$.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine as you set the indices into an explicit sequence. :)

Answer (score 3):

For $N\in \mathbb{N}$ let $$r_{n,N}=-N+{1\over N}n,\quad n=0,1,\ldots, 2N$$
and $s_{n,N}=r_{n,N}+{1\over N}.$
Let $f\in C_K(\mathbb{R}).$ Then $f$ is uniformly continuous. Hence for $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ for $|x-y|<\delta. $ Then for $N>\delta^{-1}$ we have $|r_{n,N}-s_{n,N}|={1\over N}<\delta$ and
$$\left |\int f(x)\,d\mu_{n,N}(x)-\int f(x)\,d\nu_{n,N}(x)\right |=|f(r_{n,N})-f(s_{n,N})|<\varepsilon$$ Fix $(a,b).$ Then $[a,b]\subset (-N,N)$ for  $N$ large enough. We may assume that $b-a>{1\over N}.$ Thus there exists $n$ such that $r_{n,N}<b$ and $r_{n,N}+{1\over N}\ge b.$ In particular
$r_{n,N}\ge b-{1\over N}>a.$ Hence  $s_{n,N}\ge b.$ We obtain $\mu_{n,N}(a,b)=1$ and $\nu_{n,N}(a,b)=0.$ Therefore $\mu_{n,N}(a,b)-\nu_{n,N}(a,b)=1$ for infinitely many $(n,N).$

Comment: Why is $\mu_n(a,b)=1$? For this you need $b-\frac 1 n <r_n<b$ for infinitely many $n$. Is that guaranteed?

Comment: In $0<b-r_n<{1\over n}$ you need the same $n$ in the middle and last terms. How is that guaranteed?

Comment: @geetha290krm I was too fast in answering. Thanks for pointing out the gap.

Comment: It seems that we got the same idea, with almost the same notations :)